# Show annotations not working

Tags: eclipse, egit

I use Eclipse with egit plugin. When I click Team -> Show Annotations, it shows up nothing. But I could view annotations by going to the history and then right clicking on the desired change set.

Shouldn't the first way show annotations from the latest version of that file I am working on?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of how the editor looks after show annotations? It could be that quick diff is disabled (right click on the left editor margin and select *Show Quick Diff*).

Comment: @Vignesh I have exactly the same problem (using Eclipse Kepler v4.3.0 and Git v1.8.1) - did you ever find out how to resolve this?

Comment: I am having the same problem as well, when i do "show annotations" it opens the history view but does not show the annotations on the editor

Comment: Same here. The first time I did this it opened a dialog that said something about the team provider, but I can't remember exactly what it said.

Answer (score 29):

I found [eclipse bug 394161](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394161) that says the show annotations functionality won't work unless you set your EGit preferences to ignore whitespace changes. You can do that by going to Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git and checking the box that says "Ignore whitespace changes". That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: That was it. Now it's easy for me to blame the right person for a broken code ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that when the option to ignore white space changes is already set and the blame annotations still don't work, it helps to deselect the option, click "OK", reenter, select it and confirm again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and this worked for me (in two different computers):

1. Make sure annotations are well set up, for example, if you want to see errors on the vertical ruler, you must have that option activated. **Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Errors > Show in > Vertical ruler**
2. Make sure your project is marked as a PyDev project. Right-click on your **project > PyDev > Set as PyDev Project** (if you see *Remove PyDev Project config* it is already marked as one)
3. Lastly, make sure your source folder is correctly identified. Right-click on your **source folder > PyDev > Set as source folder (add to PYTHONPATH)**

In the last step, if you see *Set as non-source folder (remove from PYTHONPATH)* it is already marked as one and, in that case, this solution shouldn't work for you, but you can try to undo and redo steps 2 and 3.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler, PyDev 3.2 and EGit 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head on this for a bit today. Right-clicking a file in Project Explorer or Package Explorer, then selecting "Team" > "Show Annotations" does not work (at least in version 4.5.1).  So don't do that. I found the easiest way to show annotations is just click on the vertical ruler then select "Show Annotations" from there.

By the way, the ignore whitespace bug that @Derek mentions has been fixed. From the [bug ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394161),

> After updating to the 3.4.0.201405071430 showing the annotations worked also without setting the property "Ignore whitespace changes"
>   So the bug seems to be fixed.

I verified that I am not impacted by the bug in 4.5.1