# Showing Annotations in Eclipse Mars for Java is Impossible

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently trying to get the git annotations in eclipse mars for a Java file, to see when a line was changed. In Luna, this worked (and still works) with `Team -> Show annotations`. In Mars, this does not work for me. (Also after reinstall and on a different computer). For other files, for example the pom.xml of the maven project, this works. The project is, besides, this problem, working and compiling fine in eclipse and was created based on the pom.xml in eclipse. Also when the project is created via `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, show annotations is not working.

I've read the settings with `Ignore whitespace changes` and `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Errors > Show in > Vertical ruler` ([Show annotations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726389/show-annotations-not-working)), which are correct. Also closing and reopening the Java perspective did not work (https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1011988/). I could not find any other recent threads about this.

Is there some configuration for Java that I am missing, or is this an eclipse bug?

Comment: In binary world everything is possible. I know many will not agree with me, but NetBeans is a life changer. I'm not seeing weird bugs any more when I've switched to NetBeans + Maven/Gradle.

Answer (score 6):

- Right click on the file . Team -> "Show Revision Information" -  in
  Eclipse Neon.
- Right click on file -> Team -> Show Annotations. - In previous eclipse versions

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Did you check if your Git repository is imported correctly? For some reason mine wasn't.

Check the Git repositories view (Window > Show view > Other > Git > Git Repositories). If you cannot see the repo there, add it and afterwards you should be able to choose "see annotations" under team.

Comment: I re-imported and got Team > Show In History back but never got "see annotations" back. puzzling.

Comment: @user2568374 as far as I remember I did not re-import the project into Eclipse, I added it to Git Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit old, but maybe to close this question.

You will have to "share" your projects.
Right click the project/projects -> Team -> Share Project.

I did select all relevant projects first and then right-clicked to share the projects. Sometimes this does not work, if a project is in the selection list, that has different porperties.

This will connect your project with your git repo.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I can not check this solution due to the fact that eclipse neon recognizes that the project is managed by git automatically again..

Comment: @David, ok sorry, you wrote Mars on top. Nevertheless, if you assume that mars/neon works correctly here, the problem might be in you git settings in Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I had the problem in eclipse mars. Since the problem didn't appear in newer versions, like mars, neon again, I can't check the answer.